# ImportError: No module named pyDes

Tags: python, python-3.x, des, 3des

I am trying to use DES and 3DES in python but when I tried to import pyDes I got this Error

ImportError: No module named pyDes

Why?

**UPDATE**

thank you

```
 from pyDes import *
    Message=(input("Enter message"))
    key=(input("Enter Key"))
    k = des(key, CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
    d = k.encrypt(message)
    print ("Encrypted: %r" % d)
    print ("Decrypted: %r" % k.decrypt(d))
```

when I run my code with this key 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
I got this error even though I'm sure it's 64 bit

```
  k = des(key, CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
   File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pyDes.py", line 400, in __init__
   raise ValueError("Invalid DES key size. Key must be exactly 8 bytes long.")
   ValueError: Invalid DES key size. Key must be exactly 8 bytes long.
```

Comment: How did you install `pyDes`?

Comment: pip install pydes

Answer (score 1):

Here is all you need: http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html
If you need any more help you should state more information fe: what you tried to do so far?